# Unable to extend FOS Controller

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I have followed [this reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_controllers.html), but the logic I change it is not applied.

The AcmeUserBundle is active at the AppKernel.php file.

Any ideas what am I skipping?

Comment: No. If you followed the docs exactly it should work, so you should follow the docs. :) Maybe try to clear the cache and please, provide more details as nobody will be able to answer your question.

Comment: clear the cache has done the trick

Comment: @1ed please write an answer, so question author can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As 1ed commented in the question it was a matter to clean the cache.